# What is Williams' "reflexively deformed" virtue, what does it mean?

Tags: virtue-ethics

What is Williams' "reflexively deformed" virtue, what does it mean? I came across that phrase trying to find out if, for Williams, integrity is unequivocally no virtue and just a quality of character. Is that a certainty, that his "integrity" is no virtue?

Comment: *Nescio*, but Mr. Williams' does what every person, if permitted, does ... naturally so.

Comment: I like this Williams guy, whoever he is. Is he on Wikipedia? The notion has a parallel in the physical world and it's an amazing insight.